# Congratulations Language Learning!

Tags: discussion

Language Learning is moving on to public beta! Congratulations and thank you to everyone who helped build this site from the ground up, and I hope to see even more participation, activity, and interest surrounding this great community in the future!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I thought I would share the "private beta review" of this site. Nothing particularly Earth-shattering or surprising; everything came together very smoothly for this site.

> **Recommendation:** Move to public beta on schedule
>
> I am pleasantly surprised just how "on topic" this site has been able to remain. My concern was that this site could potentially become a "miscellaneous language" site for questions that do not yet have a specific-language site of their own. They do have a few specific-language questions, but they have been able to properly maintain them on the correct *how-to/learning* -side of their scope.
>
> No concerns. They'll hit about 150 questions in their third week. High quality; good breadth. They are ready to go!

Comment: Very good review! Just wondering, did you write this, or someone else?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 I've been responsible for initiating and finalizing the early site activities (with input from the community team) for about a year.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, Congratulations!

I have loved being a part of this site which I joined on the first day of Private Beta. But great job to everyone still!

Comment: Agreed. Wonder how everyonee else feels about this